# wrong format in scanf C programming

Tags: c

When I doing my assigment , I am string to use this format `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",s);` in putty but it said

```
writing into constant object (argument 2) [-Wformat=]    
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",s);
```

I want to input string with white space:

```
const s[10000];
```

Comment: How is `s` defined? Is it a string literal?

Comment: I want to input string with white space, const char s[10000]

Comment: const s[10000] is wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `const char s[10000]` --> `char s[10000]`

Code cannot write to a `const` array.  It is not a format issue for `scanf()`.